# can you add HTTPS functionality to a python flask web server?

Tags: python, rest, https, flask

I am trying to build a web interface to Mock up a restful interface on networking device this networking device uses Digest Authentication and HTTPS.
I figured out how to integrate Digest Authentication into the web server but I cannot seem to find out how to get https using FLASK if you can show me how please comment on what i would need to do with the code below to make that happen.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Flask is running!'


@app.route('/data')
def names():
    data = {"names": ["John", "Jacob", "Julie", "Jennifer"]}
    return jsonify(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: If you just need to run the app over SSL _locally_, you can simply change the last line to be `app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')`, which [generates a self-signed certificate](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https). You can easily click through this in your browser since you trust yourself when developing locally, but not a viable solution for production.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

this also works in a pinch

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify


from OpenSSL import SSL
context = SSL.Context(SSL.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.use_privatekey_file('server.key')
context.use_certificate_file('server.crt')   


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Flask is running!'


@app.route('/data')
def names():
    data = {"names": ["John", "Jacob", "Julie", "Jennifer"]}
    return jsonify(data)


#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    app.run()
if __name__ == '__main__':  
     app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True, ssl_context=context)
```

Comment: SSLv3 has POODLE vulnerability. Change it to TSL

Comment: Following this link : http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/111/  At the end of the page a comment explains how to change to TSL.

Comment: You mean TLS not TSL?

Comment: This code for creating the `context` is deprecated for newer python. Try this: 
```import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.load_cert_chain('certificate.crt', 'private.key')```

Comment: I think the API here is obsolete.  [My answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65152383/1277934) gives a version of this that worked with Python 3.7.5.

Answer (score 91):

## Don't use **openssl or pyopenssl** its now become obselete in python

Refer the Code below

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import os

ASSETS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Flask is running!'


@app.route('/data')
def names():
    data = {"names": ["John", "Jacob", "Julie", "Jennifer"]}
    return jsonify(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = ('local.crt', 'local.key')#certificate and key files
    app.run(debug=True, ssl_context=context)
```

Comment: To generate `local.crt` and `local.key` see Method 2 of: http://kracekumar.com/post/54437887454/ssl-for-flask-local-development

Comment: weird, it runs at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. is not this supposed to run on secure http. I Still can GET at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

Comment: I was looking on how to implement SSL on a Dash app and this answer did the trick, here is the code: `context = ('local.crt','local.key')  if __name__ == "__main__":     app.run_server(host="192.168.200.100", port="8082", debug=True, ssl_context=context)`

Comment: I'm using google cloud run. In this case, for production, I only need to buy a certificate from a CA and them put it into my app following your answer?

Comment: This is running fine for me, but when I use ssl_context=context my index.html does not load the linked .css and .js local files anymore. When I run the app with ssl_context=None the html loads them with no problem. Any help here?

Comment: @MatheusTorquato This is because, apparently, the default values for `ssl_context`, or `ssl_context = context` loads a set of restrictions that, essentially, lock down the site extremely tightly. At the site discussing Talisman as a way to secure Flask, (https://betterprogramming.pub/from-http-to-https-easily-secure-flask-web-apps-with-talisman-3359692d3eac), they say that for the usual site using SSL, this may not be necessary.  Of course, that depends on your site and YMMV.

Answer (score 35):

- To run HTTPS functionality or SSL authentication in your flask application, first install "pyOpenSSL" python package

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

- Next step is to create `cert.pem` and `key.pem`

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365
```

- Copy generated `cert.pem` and `key.pem` in your flask application project
- Add `ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem')` in `app.run()`, like in the example below.

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():

    return "Flask is running!"


@app.route("/data")
def names():

    data = {"names": ["John", "Jacob", "Julie", "Jennifer"]}

    return jsonify(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(ssl_context=("cert.pem", "key.pem"))
```

Comment: i got an error after first step as `openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: Did you installed pyopenssl?

Comment: yes i have installed ....later when I am trying step 2 `to create 'cert.pem' and 'key.pem'` it shown me the error

Comment: You have to add it to path if you are in windows.

Comment: You also have to download it. From the website, not from pip.

Comment: When you used `-days 365`, it means that every years you need to update your certificate ? Is there a way to keep certificate always updated and working ?

Answer (score 23):

For a quick n' dirty self-signed cert, you can also use `flask run --cert adhoc` or set the `FLASK_RUN_CERT` env var.

```
$ export FLASK_APP="app.py"
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ export FLASK_RUN_CERT=adhoc

$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on https://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 329-665-000
```

The `adhoc` option isn't well documented (for good reason, never do this in production), but it's mentioned in the [cli.py source code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/38eb5d3b49d628785a470e2e773fc5ac82e3c8e4/src/flask/cli.py#L691-L694).

There's a thorough explanation of this by [Miguel Grinberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904393/miguel) at [Running Your Flask Application Over HTTPS](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https).

Comment: I'm using google cloud run. In this case, for production, I only need to buy a certificate from a CA and them put it into my app following your answer?

Answer (score 22):

[The top-scoring answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29464090/1277934) has the right idea, but the API seems to have evolved so that it no longer works as when it was first written, in 2015.

In place of this:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
context = SSL.Context(SSL.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.use_privatekey_file('server.key')
context.use_certificate_file('server.crt')
```

I used this, with Python 3.7.5:

```
import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.load_cert_chain('fullchain.pem', 'privkey.pem')
```

and then supplied the SSL context in the `Flask.run` call as it said:

```
app.run(…, ssl_context=context)
```

(My `server.crt` file is called `fullchain.pem` and my `server.key` is called `privkey.pem`.  These files were supplied to me by my LetsEncrypt Certbot.)

Comment: what about SSL POODLE vulnerability?

Comment: I'm using google cloud run. In this case I only need to buy a certificate from a CA and them put it into my app following your answer?

Comment: Hey Mark how exactly did you generate those crt pem and key?

Comment: bah forget that I see the server.crt and key we just renamed I used openssl on wsl to generate them

Comment: DeprecationWarning: ssl.SSLContext() without protocol argument is deprecated.

Answer (score 19):

Deploy Flask on a real web server, rather than with the built-in (development) server.

See the [*Deployment Options* chapter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/) of the Flask documentation. Servers like Nginx and Apache both can handle setting up HTTPS servers rather than HTTP servers for your site.

The standalone WSGI servers listed would typically be deployed behind Nginx and Apache in a proxy-forwarding configuration, where the front-end server handles the SSL encryption for you still.

Comment: If you use mod_wsgi-express (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi) it provides an easy way of running up a site with HTTPS, plus has builtin capabilities for handling Digest authentication protocol at the web server level as well. Suggest you ask about it on the mod_wsgi mailing list as StackOverflow is not a discussion forum and so not as easily explained here.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, Could you please explain why we should "Deploy Flask on a real web server, rather than with the built-in (development) server."? Thanks

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland: the built-in server is not equipped to deal with the 'real world' of the internet, it has not been battlehardened from a security POV nor has it been tuned for performance. It's primary purpose is to bootstrap development on a local machine, nothing more. Using it in a production environment is at your own risk, which in my opinion is a rather large risk.

Comment: using a real webserver is not always an option, i just want to serve some files with Flask and https

Comment: @mazs: then you take the security risk. And it's trivial to install gunicorn and use that to serve your Flask, that server at least is much more battle hardened.

Answer (score 7):

If this webserver is only for testing and demoing purposes. You can use ngrok, a open source too that tunnels your http traffic.

Bascially ngrok creates a public URL (both http and https) and then tunnels the traffic to whatever port your Flask process is running on.

https://ngrok.com/product

It only takes a couple minutes to set up. You first have to download the software. Then run the command
./ngrok http [port number your python process is running on]

It will then open up a window in terminal giving you both an http and https url to access your web app.

Comment: This really worked without much hassle of installing/configuring stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Super simple:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

**run:**

```
$ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365
$ flask run --cert=cert.pem --key=key.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) to generate certificate that is trusted by browsers.

```
mkcert example.com "*.example.com" example.test localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

Browser will trust all of the following domains and IPs

```
- "example.com"
- "*.example.com"
- "example.test"
- "localhost"
- "127.0.0.1"
- "::1"
```

---

**Python Code:**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():

    return "Welcome to the Python Flask's Index!"



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=443, ssl_context=("localhost+3.pem", "localhost+3-key.pem"))
```

**Screenshot:**
[image: screenshot]