# Installing HTTPS for my web app in DigitalOcean, `https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` is okay but not with, `https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1234`

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean, self-signed

I followed these tutorials.

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04, without the step 5.
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04, without the, "(Recommended) Modify the Unencrypted Virtual Host File to Redirect to HTTPS" part.
- I put `ServerName server_domain_or_IP` with `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1234`.

What I have now.

- `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1234` goes to my web application. I need SSL to access webcam.
- `https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` goes to Apache default screen after warning, which is expected.
- `https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1234` goes Chrome error page of `This site can’t provide a secure connection`.

I need to have access to `https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1234` what went wrong and what should I do?

EDIT, More details.

- Fresh install with SSH attached into the droplet (Ubuntu LTS 16.04).
- `ssh root@xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx`.
- `adduser notalentgeek`.
- `usermod -aG sudo notalentgeek`.
- `su notalentgeek`.
- Now I am on the newly created user `notalentgeek`.
- Move into "How To Create a Self-Signed SSL Certificate for Apache in Ubuntu 16.04" tutorial.
- `sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt`.
- In the form I put everything as "asd" (any arbitrary thing in my mind, are these matters). Except for "Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:" is to ip of `xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx`.
- `sudo openssl dhparam -out /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem 2048` and wait for a while.
- `sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/ssl-params.conf`.
- Copy paste the settings from the tutorial (**StackOverflow code formatting does not working here!**).

  ## from https://cipherli.st/

  ## and https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_Apache2.html

  SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
  SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder On

  ## Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes

  ## the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.

  ## Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"

  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains"
  Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

  ## Requires Apache >= 2.4

  SSLCompression off 
  SSLSessionTickets Off
  SSLUseStapling on 
  SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"

  SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters "/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem"
- `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf.bak` to create backup.
- `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`.

  ServerAdmin asd@asd.com
                  ServerName xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx

  ```
              DocumentRoot /var/www/html

              ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
              CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

              SSLEngine on

              SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
              SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

              <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                              SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
              </FilesMatch>
              <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                              SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
              </Directory>

              BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

      </VirtualHost>
  ```
- `sudo ufw app list`, adjusting fire wall. I just put whatever codes they put there.
- `sudo ufw status`.
- `sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'`.
- `sudo ufw delete allow 'Apache'`.
- `sudo ufw status`.
- `sudo a2enmod ssl`.
- `sudo a2enmod headers`.
- `sudo a2ensite default-ssl`.
- `sudo a2enconf ssl-params`.
- `sudo apache2ctl configtest`, there is no warning appeared in my case. But, in the tutorial it may have warning. This command returns, `Syntax OK`.
- Testing server as I mentioned before, `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` works, but `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000` does not (5000 is my port for Flask.).
- `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
- Add `Redirect permanent "/" "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/"`.
- `sudo apache2ctl configtest` results in `Syntax OK`.
- `sudo systemctl restart apache2`.
- This the launch from my Flask App.

> WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent and gevent-websocket for improved performance.
>   * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

- Going to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/`, where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is the IP of DigitalOcean Droplet refer to my web app successfully. But web app needs access to webcam and microphone.
- Following other tutorial, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps.
- `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi python-dev`.
- `sudo a2enmod wsgi`.
- `cd /var/www`.
- `sudo mkdir FlaskApp`.
- `cd FlaskApp`.
- `git clone https://github.com/notalentgeek/my_app --depth 1`.
- `cd my_app`.
- Installing, `pip3` and `virtualenv`. Running from `http` is still fine!
- `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf` (formatting also does not working!).

  ServerName https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/
      ServerAdmin asd@asd.com
      WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
      
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
      
      Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/my_app/static
      
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
      
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      LogLevel warn
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
- `sudo a2ensite FlaskApp`.
- `cd /var/www/FlaskApp`.
- `sudo nano flaskapp.wsgi`.
- `sudo service apache2 restart`, the tutorial says that would be a warning message. but I did not get any.
- `sudo python3 -B my_app.py` results in these.

> WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent and gevent-websocket for improved performance.
>   * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

- In `http` all work but not `https`.

Some of the codes has `##` make the indent-to-code in StackOverflow does not working. Here is the raw from PasteBin, https://pastebin.com/iShsHjCX.

Comment: Please describe what steps you undertook inside your question; do not rely solely on external resources for an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing solved me, [can you add HTTPS functionality to a python flask web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458548/can-you-add-https-functionality-to-a-python-flask-web-server). It is more in the Flask side rather than anything else.