# How to run localhost with HTTPS in flask?

Tags: python, ssl, flask, https

I generated private key and self-signed certificate using:

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

Created `context` as below:

```py
from OpenSSL import SSL

context = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD)
context.use_certificate('localhost.crt')
context.use_privatekey('localhost.key')
```

And ran flask app in two ways (none of them worked):

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(ssl_context=('localhost.crt', 'localhost.key'), debug=True)
```

OR

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', ssl_context=context, debug=True)
```

Finally,

```py
python app.py
```

Yet, it doesn't run on https.
How can I run as: https://localhost:5000 ?

Comment: There is a nice howto on running https: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https

Comment: @gittert, I tried the two ways: simple and self-signed. It didn't worked.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more than only 'it didn't work'. What code did you use, which packages were imported, what does it say in console when running the app, etc.

Comment: The server always runs at: http://127.0.0.1:5000. I also tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42906465/9924439 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29464090/9924439.

Answer (score 1):

The way you generate the certificate and the `ssl_context` setup is working.

I'm guessing you run the application with Flask command e.g. `flask run` but your `ssl_context` setup is inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement meaning it will be executed this way only if you execute this file directly e.g. `python app.py` assuming that the file is called `app.py`.

By default flask runs app on http hence it is missing https.

Comment: Now it says: "TypeError: cert must be an X509 instance". FYI, run function definition is as follows: `def run(self, host=None, port=None, debug=None, load_dotenv=True, **options):` I have also added to my question how I created the context.

Comment: Run your app with command `python app.py` assuming your application file is called `app.py` and it should work.