# certfile and keyfile FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, flask, pyopenssl

I have created a flask app which also has dash in it and i am working on windows 64 bit.
I have installed pyopenssl and after running below code

```
app.run_server(debug=False,ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'))
```

after running code i get below mentioned error:

```
  File "~\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1402, in wrap_socket
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Please help to resolve it, as I am new to python please explain in detail...

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Did you generate 'cert.pem' and 'key.pem' file? If so where have you placed it?

Comment: not generated..how to generate it..please help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52295688/4374376 follow this answer.

Comment: i copied same code to generate cert and key file : ``` openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365''', but still facing some error in terminal, i am using annaconda and then used the terminal there god some weird error

Comment: What error you are getting? What is your system?

Comment: My System is Windows 10 , I first installed pyopenssl from annaconda prompt and used this above mentioned Certificate creation code in Annaconda prompt which gave some error like :                               Can't open D:\bld\openssl_split_1596005313510\_h_env\Library/openssl.cnf for reading, No such file or directory
7044:error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:69:fopen('D:\bld\openssl_split_1596005313510\_h_env\Library/openssl.cnf','r')
7044:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto\bio\bss_file.c:76:

Answer (score 0):

1. ) first open terminal, go to the your code folder.
2. ) create new folder :> `mkdir certs` and :> `cd certs`  go new created certs folder
3. ) next install this library :> `pip install pyopenssl`
4. ) copy and past this:> `code:> openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365`
5. ) finally answer the questions asked.
6. ) Done your 'cert.pem', 'key.pem' created.