# How to enable HTTPS on a Python Flask website

Tags: python, flask, ssl, ssl-certificate, waitress

I have a Python Flask website hosted on a Windows VPS at Hetzner, a SSL key with Certbot and a OVH domain name.
My website is only working on HTTP and I can't find how can I enable HTTPS with it. I already linked my SSL key in OVH, but I think I need to do something else on the server itself but I don't know how it works. Thanks for any help!

Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
from waitress import serve

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #context = ('server.crt', 'server.key')
    #app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=80, ssl_context=context)
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=80, threads=1, url_scheme='https') # I tried
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458548/can-you-add-https-functionality-to-a-python-flask-web-server).

But i really dont recommand add `https` in `flask` server.
Instead, you may consider using `reverse proxy` like `nginx` to provide `ssl` support.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;
    server_name  _;
    charset utf-8;

    ssl_certificate   /etc/nginx/cert/xxx.pem;  // add ssl certificate
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/cert/xxxx.key;  // add ssl certificate
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location ^~ / {
        proxy_pass http://flask:5000;  // redirect to flask
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr:$remote_port;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work on a Windows server like OP asks? Your paths suggest Unix. I have yet to see *any* Windows https solution for flask/waitress/nginx anywhere online.