# http request on azure VM for python

Tags: python, azure-virtual-machine

I know this is not a direct code related question but more a best practices. I have several azure HTTPfunctions running but they timeout due to long calculations. I have added Durable orchestrations but even they time out.

As certain processes are long and time consuming (aka training an AI model) I have switched to Azure VM. What I would like to add to this is the possibility to start an Python task from an HTTP request on my azure VM.

basically doing the exact same as the Azure HTTPFunctions. What would be the best way to do this, any great documentation or recommendations much appreciated. So running an API on my VM in Python.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go around this would be to

1. Set up a Python webserver (e.g. [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/)) on your VM,
2. Enable inbound requests to your VM (some Info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/366073/expose-python-api-from-vm)), and then
3. Make http requests to your webserver via the VM's Public address.

If it's important your server resource has a https connection, you could obtain the needed certificates using [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions), and mention the certificate files in the initialisation of your webserver (as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458548/can-you-add-https-functionality-to-a-python-flask-web-server)).

If you intend for your server to handle a good amount of traffic, you can look into incorporating production servers like gunicorn, nginx (some Information [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https)).