# Dockerized Python Flask app to use https instead of http

Tags: docker, flask, server, https

I have a server and on that server I am running a dockerized Flask app. The app works with HTTP, but I need it to work with HTTPS to communicate with my website. I am accessing my API with and IP address like this: http://46.102.22.4:5000/players

I created a self-assigned SSL certificate like this:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 \
            -x509 \
            -sha256 \
            -days 3650 \
            -nodes \
            -out certificate.crt \
            -keyout private.key
```

I then renamed certificate.crt and private.key to certificate.pem and privateKey.pem and added this code to my app.py:

```
import ssl
ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
ctx.load_cert_chain('certificate.pem', 'privateKey.pem')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, ssl_context=ctx)
```

I also opened port 443 with `sudo ufw allow 443`
And then also exposed the ports 80 and 443 in Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

After all this the HTTPS is still not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can you add HTTPS functionality to a python flask web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458548/can-you-add-https-functionality-to-a-python-flask-web-server)